# Hiding titlebar in Firefox?

Tags: icons, firefox, minimize, title-bar

[image]

Why are both **close** and **minimize** icons both on the left? Is it possible to make minimize icon appear on the right?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed! To do this you need to open the customization options in Firefox (via the Firefox menu), and enable the "Title Bar" option in the bottom left of the window. This will enable the system-style titlebars and borders, including proper positioning of window controls.

[image]